# SSL access failure

Tags: windows, ssl, bazel

I deployed a bazel-remote-cache in a kubernetes cluster. I secured the communication with TLS and used company signed certificates.

Remote-cache-image: buchgr/bazel-remote-cache:v2.1.4

args:

```
        - --dir=/data
        - --max_size=15
        - --host=0.0.0.0
        - --http_read_timeout=60s
        - --http_write_timeout=60s
        - --s3.endpoint=$(endpoint)
        - --s3.region=$(region)
        - --s3.secret_access_key=$(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        - --s3.access_key_id=$(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
        - --s3.bucket=bazel-remote-cache-dev
        - --s3.prefix=test 
        - --htpasswd_file=/cred/.htpasswd
        - --tls_cert_file=/cred/certificate-request-name.cer
        - --tls_key_file=/cred/private-key-name.key
        - --allow_unauthenticated_reads
```

Via Curl command I am getting following result:
curl https://dev.brc.com/project/cas/e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

which should be fine.

Once I am trying to build with bazel with following flag for remote cache:

```
--remote_cache=https://dev.brc.com/project
```

I am getting following
**error:**

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:674)
        at io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:577)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1141)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1256)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:212)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1330)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1272)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:242)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:670)
        ... 30 more
```

**Platform**:
Windows 10

**Bazel version**:
4.1.0

I guess that bazel uses its own Java trust store by default. (not sure if this is a correct statement)
Based on that I tried following:

bazel 
--host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NULL 
--host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
build //...

but this ends up with another error:

```
Internal error thrown during build. Printing stack trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: unable to setup trustmanager
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.RemoteCacheClientFactory.createHttp(RemoteCacheClientFactory.java:130)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.RemoteCacheClientFactory.create(RemoteCacheClientFactory.java:80)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.RemoteModule.beforeCommand(RemoteModule.java:156)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeCommandDispatcher.execExclusively(BlazeCommandDispatcher.java:358)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.runtime.BlazeCommandDispatcher.exec(BlazeCommandDispatcher.java:208)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.server.GrpcServerImpl.executeCommand(GrpcServerImpl.java:603)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.server.GrpcServerImpl.lambda$run$2(GrpcServerImpl.java:659)
        at io.grpc.Context$1.run(Context.java:595)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: unable to setup trustmanager
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:163)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslClientContext.<init>(OpenSslClientContext.java:192)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:777)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:452)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.http.HttpCacheClient.<init>(HttpCacheClient.java:242)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.http.HttpCacheClient.create(HttpCacheClient.java:154)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.remote.RemoteCacheClientFactory.createHttp(RemoteCacheClientFactory.java:120)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.newSessionContext(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:142)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Windows-ROOT not found
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(Unknown Source)
        ... 19 more
```

I would like avoid using keytool to add any certificates to java trust store since the certifcates should be already available on Windows certificate store.
Did anyone face similar issues and know how to fix it or have any suggestion what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using client certificates? Also, can you confirm you're using `https:` (not `grpcs:`)? If you post all the flags you're using, it would answer those and more questions about your setup.

Comment: Hi @BrianSilverman ,
I am not using client certificates (mTLS) and I can confirm that I am using https. I extended my above description with more information.
Thanks already for your support

Comment: I believe you are using a self signed cert, which bazel env can not trust.
This link might be helpful: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/testdata/test_tls_certificate/README.md

Comment: Useful info : https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12225